# UseEffect Loading Screen not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display the loading screen.

Here is my code. I put the `setLoading(true)` and `setLoading(false)` in useEffect as the following

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setDescription(callnamePassed);
      setName(namePassed);
      setCompany(companyPassed);
      setEmail(emailPassed);
      setPhone(phonePassed);
      setAddress(addressPassed);
      setAddressTwo(addressTwoPassed);
      setZip(zipPassed);
      setCity(cityPassed);
      setState(statePassed);
      setCountry(countryPassed);
      setModalOneValue(countryPassed);
      setIsDefault(isDefaultPassed);
    });
    setLoading(false);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [route]);
```

I am using this in the details screen when different items details are displayed.
Let say we got `detail A and B`.

When I go into the `details A` for the first time. The loading animations is working fine.
but If I go back to parent screen and go to `detailsB` no loading animation is showing.

Component look something like this

```
return (<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <View>...</View>))
```

Comment: So you have screen A and Screen B , when you navigate from A to B loading animation works  but when you go back to A and navigate to B again , loading animations doesn't show up right ?

Comment: @HassanKandil A and B got parent screen when I go back from A to parent then go into B animation not working

Comment: The navigation listener placed in parent or in B please clarify ?

Comment: This `focus` listener is placed inside the child component.
The parent doesn't need loading screen.

Comment: @Kerry Loading animation must be inside the focus listener I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setLoading(true);
      setDescription(callnamePassed);
      ....
    });
    setLoading(false);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [route]);
```

Comment: For Some reason the loading never goes away :3